# Stored Procedure test to return recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I began to write this SP only to find out it doesn't work.  I don't want to have to ping the server twice if I don't have to.  I basically need to cherry pick parts where the trays already exist (variables specified as parameters), and if they don't exist, just pick the top part.  The problem is, is that I want to return this as a recordset, so I get the next X amount of parts.  I need to be "predictive" with the trays.

```
SET @test = (SELECT [SERIAL_NUMBER] FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] 
    WHERE ([RACK] = @leftStack AND [TRAY] = @leftTray) 
    OR ([RACK] = @midStack AND [TRAY] = @midTray) 
    OR ([RACK] = @rightStack AND [TRAY] = @rightTray))

IF NULLIF(@test, '') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 6 [RACK], [TRAY], [POSITION] FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] 
            WHERE ([RACK] = @leftStack AND [TRAY] = @leftTray) 
            OR ([RACK] = @midStack AND [TRAY] = @midTray) 
            OR ([RACK] = @rightStack AND [TRAY] = @rightTray)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 6 [RACK], [TRAY], [POSITION] FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS]
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your SELECT test assign the value to your variable, like this:

```
SELECT @test = [SERIAL_NUMBER] FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] 
WHERE ([RACK] = @leftStack AND [TRAY] = @leftTray) 
    OR ([RACK] = @midStack AND [TRAY] = @midTray) 
    OR ([RACK] = @rightStack AND [TRAY] = @rightTray)
```

Comment: Ah easy miss I guess.  I've been on 'cruise control' all day :)